# PHP, Codeigniter Session Login

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
function login_proses() {
    $username = $this->input->post('username');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');

    $chek = $this->db->get_where('tabel_users', array('username' => $username, 'password' => $password, 'status' => '1'));
    $chek2 = $this->db->get_where('tabel_users', array('username' => $username, 'password' => $password, 'status' => '0'));

    if ($chek->num_rows() > 0 ) {
      $this->session->set_userdata(array('username' => $username, 'status_login_admin' => 'sudah_login'));
      redirect('admin/home');
    }
    else if ($chek2->num_rows() > 0 ) {
      $this->session->set_userdata(array('username' => $username, 'status_login_sekda' => 'sudah_login'));
      redirect('admin/home_sekda');
    }
    else {
      $this->template->load('templatelogin','admin/login/login_error');   
    }  
  }
```

when i run that code and i insert the username and password for chek2 i cant access the chek2 and its back to the login form

how can i make the code work so i can access the home_sekda

Comment: just echo your query result. then update your questions. there is nothing we can figure out from this. it looks fine

Comment: when i try query for the $chek is working fine
when im use username and password for check2 its not redirect to admin/home_sekda
its back to admin/login 

and when i try to replace chek with $chek2 on the first if its working fine
and i cant acces the $chek instead of $chek2

Comment: Can you provide more detail?? What is the field `status` mean?? Why are you querying it twice?? Explain it correctly. Only then somebody can help.